# Position Specifiers appearing in final pdf document using memoir

Tags: floats, memoir

I am using the `memoir` class to generate my thesis and when I declare a figure or table using a position specifier, where the position specifier is `h`, `t`, etc., my final PDF document has the label/position specifier printed over the figure.

I am using

```
\begin{figure}[h]
```

to declare my figure.

In this case my figure prints where i want it but prints 'h' above the figure.

Any ideas as to what's going on or how to fix would be much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It is considered a lot better to put in some code that will compile, as it makes it a lot easier for us to copy it into our text editor and work with it, and see exactly what it is you are trying to do.

Comment: I had trouble getting a minimal example working as i am using a large stylefile that I have been piecing together for some time. If it helps anyone else though, in trying to produce a minimal working example I discovered the root of the problem. \renewenvironment{figure}{\@float{figure}\sffamily\mathversion{sans}}{\end@float} - i have reverted to using the standard figure environment.

Comment: It's clearly that definition that produces the problem. Please, add the code to your question and a workaround will be provided.

Comment: You probably need simply `\captionnamefont{\sffamily}`
and `\captiontitlefont{\sffamily\mathversion{sans}}`

Comment: % Caption styling
\captionnamefont{\sffamily\small\bfseries\color{Heading}}
\captiontitlefont{\sffamily\small\mathversion{sans}}
\subcaptionfont{\sffamily\mathversion{sans}}
\subcaptionlabelfont{\sffamily}
\hangcaption
\hangsubcaption
\captiontitlefinal{.} This did the trick. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need text also outside of the caption in the figure environment, then you can correct your redefinition in

```
\renewenvironment{figure}[1][\fps@figure]
  {\@float{figure}[#1]\sffamily\mathversion{sans}}
  {\end@float‌​}
```

Otherwise I suggest a simpler

```
% how to typeset the caption label
\captionnamefont{\sffamily}
% how to typeset the caption text
\captiontitlefont{\sffamily\small\mathversion{sans}}
```

with maybe something similar for subcaptions.

Adjust to suit, adding other settings, if desired.

Comment: @felice Please, consider to register, so as to enjoy better the site. We wait for other contributions from you. Your name looks Italian. :)